# Am I allowed to travel to China for 72 hours without visa?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, china, lithuanian-citizens

I am a Lithuanian citizen (EU) and will need to visit the Lithuanian embassy that is in China, Beijing.

I have checked visa requirements and it would appear [I can enter the country for 72 hours without a visa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_European_Union_citizens#Other) - which would give me enough time to go about my business and come back...

**Am I indeed allowed to travel to China for 72 hours without visa?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=lt&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=cn&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines, **yes**, you can do this, **if and only if** the return flight is **not** to the same country that you flew to Beijing from.

For example, Vilnius-Moscow-Beijing and Beijing-Kiev-Vilnius is OK, but Vilnius-Moscow-Beijing and Beijing-St Petersburg-Vilnius is **not**

Comment: Hi Crazyde, thanks for the answer. So I can't do Phnom Penh -> Beijing... Beijing -> Phnom Penh...

Comment: @Matas seems like that's not possible, as you are entering China with China as destination. You're not transiting and rhus you would need a Tourist or Business visa. If you have a layover in let's say Kuala Lumpur on the way back, it would be allowed.

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius Unfortunately not. Phnom Penh-Beijing and Beijing-Hong Kong-Phnom Penh would be possible though